# const and non-const in stl containers

Tags: c++, boost, stl

The STL vector template defines element accessors as both const and non-const variants, for example:

```
reference operator[](size_type __n) 
    {return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n);}
const_reference operator[](size_type __n) const 
    {return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n);}
```

When does the compiler decide to use one version over the other? The vector itself is not defined as const, neither are the elements stored in it. So given two functions:

```
A f(int i) const
    { return myVector[i]; }
A f(int i)
    { return myVector[i]; }
```

My understanding is that the first would call the const version of operator[] and return a const A. The second calls the non-const version and returns a non-const A?

To me, the first version of f() seems to be the "correct" one to write since the function isn't altering anything, but it is perhaps surprising to the caller that it returns a const A. Surely if I wanted a const A returned, I should need to define f() as:

```
const A f(int i) const    //Note the extra const at the start
    { return myVector[i]; }
```

Which would tell whoever is writing the caller to expect a const back.

So the extra const appears by magic? And what does the extra const get applied to if I'm using a boost::ptr_vector rather than std::vector? The data? The pointer? both?

Comment: You'd be better off asking a general question about 'const'. And even better, studying this in your C++ textbook and by trying out example programs, and then possibly asking about any concrete issues. Which textbook are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This takes advantage of a tricky part of the function overload rules.  First off, cv-qualifiers after the close parenthesis of a method prototype are just like cv-qualifiers on arguments, but they apply to the implicit `this` argument.  In a hypothetical C++ variant where you had to declare `this`, the prototypes would be like so:

```
reference operator[](this_type this, size_type n);
const_reference operator[](const this_type this, size_type n);
```

Therefore, if the *object you are calling the method on* is `const`, the second overload is a closer match and will be called.  If it's not, the first overload will be called.  So you get a `const_reference` back if you index a `const` container, and you get a `reference` back if you index a non-`const` container.  The `const_reference` object then enforces the read-only nature of the container it points into.

Sometimes `const_reference` is the same as `const reference` and sometimes it isn't; for the more complicated containers, a `reference` is a class with nontrivial code, and that code has to be different for the read-only variety.  The standard consistently uses `const_reference` so that implementors have freedom to do that when they need to.

Comment: `const_reference` is almost never the same as `const reference`, except when `value_type` is already `const`. If `reference` is `int&`, `const reference` would also be `int&`, not `const int&`.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` at the end of a function declaration applies only to non-static member functions, and means that `*this` is const-qualified.

```
struct A {
  void f(int i) const;
  void f(int i);
};

void g(const A& x, A& y) {
  x.f(); // calls const version
  y.f(); // calls non-const version
}
```

In STL containers, this sort of overload is used to determine whether the returned reference or iterator can be used to change the container's elements.  You cannot change an element through a `const` qualified container.

Answer (score 1):

In the function:

```
A f(int i) const
    { return myVector[i]; }
```

You are returning a non-const A. Since you are returning by value, the value returned by operator[] (a const reference) is copied into a new A. You are "losing" the const, but it doesn't matter because you have a whole new object. Rather, if your class looks like this:

```
struct B {
  const A& f(int i) const;
  A& f(int i);

private:
  vector<A> myVector;
};
```

and you call f() using a const B:

```
const B b;
const A& a = b.f();
```

your a will be a const reference.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a const rvalue is effectively meaningless- it's perfectly legal to construct a new value from a const lvalue, which is why the first form is valid. Think about it- if you want to copy from somewhere, it doesn't matter if you can't write to that somewhere.

If you returned a reference, then the compiler would not allow you to return an A& in the const version.